# Re Zero ; kill all and start over - what genes are associated with non violence

Tags: genetics, genetic-engineering, cloning

Anyone with a perfectionism mania would understand the urge to delete and destroy everything for the smallest mistake, the most insignificant impurities are disgusting and craze inducing from the enormous mental stress they cause, the imperfections must be erased and made over again from zero.

A maniac with a lot of money and a lot of anonymous power managed to kill off humans from the planet by manipulating people in power like puppets being drawn by other puppets being drawn by the actual puppet master.

All traces of human history have been deleted, failures do not deserve to be memorized in the mind of a perfectionist, a perfectionist learns from mistakes but acts as if they never happened.

The maniac wants to build a new civilization of clones, the perfect humanity.

For now my question is: What gene strands are associated with lack of violent responses and disgust of violence, death and pain?

Like you see in the movies, when the main character hurts another person and they are traumatized, but in reality the majority of people would take pictures if they saw people burning alive in the streets...it actually does happen in India and China.

Comment: I've removed a comment extraneous to the question. We have many people here from many countries, and we'd like to keep on good terms with them.

Comment: Don't worry the villain exterminates everyone regardless of ethnicity, it's not racist if you kill them all.

Comment: That clearly wasn't what @ARogueAnt. was talking about. Please review again what he deleted.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the gene strands? Should we just point at each chromosome and say what should be deleted/added/changed? Can we solve it by just making a hyperactive hormone system that suppresses violent responses and lack of violence, or destroy parts of the Amygdala? Does it absolutely need to be DNA based, as (religious) culture can already do this for you?

Comment: "What gene strands are associated with..." - biology does not have an answer to this question. Do you want us to make it up?

Comment: Put the question on hold and ask again about one hundred years from now. At present we have only very fuzzy (and most likely entirely mistaken) ideas of how genes are related to psychological traits.

Answer (score 1):

### You can't eliminate war from the human genome, but you can eliminate antisocial behaviour.

Violent people tend to be people who genetics or upbringing gave a short fuse, who react in an abnormally angry way to perceived slights. You can stop that, but if people want to rebel they still can. Anyway, onto making a safe society.

### Tweak the MAO-A gene and similar ones to flatten mood.

People with MAO-A have altered adrenal response and react quickly to stress and pick fights more easily. You can make sure they have the most stable versions of these genes so a few stressful situations won't make them go crazy.

You can also tweak dopamine genes. You don't want people getting too excited about anything. Dopamine is the reward drug. Lower this, and your people won't get addicted to drugs as easily or chase rewards.

### You want people with stronger oxytocin genes.

Trust and family is a great deterrence against violence. If you're in a stable relationship you're less likely to decide it's a good idea to be violent, and more willing to self sacrifice for the greater good.

[Oxytocin genes](https://healthland.time.com/2011/11/17/telltale-signs-youve-got-the-love-hormone-gene/) like these should be encouraged, so that people are trusting and loving. They can have stable loving relationships and only fight when their families are in danger.

### You want lower amounts of genes that cause confident charisma.

Good leaders can form rebellions and lead your people against other factions of your people. As such, you need to [lower charismatic genes](https://www.elitedaily.com/life/culture/charisma-born-to-be-charming/1037590). This is often related to dopamine, so it should synergize well with genes that help flatten mood. You want to minimize people's ability to boldly lead each other.

All together, you can make an emotionally flat, trusting, shy society. So long as there are no threats to their loved ones, and no crisis that explode their stress responses they should be fine.

In the long run, you can experiment with things like making them harder working and sleep less so they can work harder for you, but those are long term goals.

Comment: "You can't eliminate war from the human genome" sounds like a pretty arbitrary statement, there have been comoletely peaceful tribes both in humans and other animals...plus lobotomy proves to eliminate most human emotions, why wouldn't something less invasive and more precise like gene modifications or selective breeding not work?

Comment: Which completely peaceful tribes have there been, or completely peaceful animals? I don't know any, hence why I note you can't eliminate war, without really radical modifications. 

What I mean is you can vastly lower casual violence, but people can always pick up weapons and prepare to fight rivals. You need a society that disincentives war, ruled by the scientist presumably.

Lobotomies make people childlike. They don't eliminate emotions. They blunt them, but lobotomy'd people are often violent.

Answer (score 0):

There is one to one when it comes to Genes and violence. People are violent for different reasons so it is not so simple as flipping a switch. There are things that you could change genticly  that would lower violence but they may have a lot of negative consequences.

1. Lower the human desire to compete with one another.
   There are many ways to do this all would have dramatica  And unpredictable consequences 1st you could completely change the human brain chemistry.  2nd you could fundamentally change  testosterone levels (testosterone  Promotes competition In males and females. )  Or even eliminate males from the population entirely .  Males  Produce much higher testosterone, this means they are Far more likely to compete then cooperate compared to females.  This is one of the reasons violent crimes are so much higher for males than females.
2. Change the flight or fight response. Violence isn't always  also caused by competition often it is a response to threat or perceived threat.   Humans have 3 responses to a threat  Fight, flight and freeze.  If you could Alter human brain and physiology enough as to eliminate the fight response you might see a decrease in violence.

It should be noted that none of these changes would eleminate violence completely

Comment: You might also want to change the genes that allow for fast population growth. Throughout human history, populations have been kept in check through war and the attendant famine and plague. Without the need to limit population growth, there is far less push for violence.

Comment: @David R depends on the tec level the new humans start at up to the modern era most civilization need the as many workers as the could get